# get the data of rows and columns of ListView in windows based application using C# and LeanFT

Tags: c#, leanft

is there anyway to get the data of rows and columns of listview for windows based application in C#?

or

can any one show a code for getting rows and columns from listview?

Comment: It might help to show us what you have tried... Code examples are a plus here. This might help with future posts: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This is what you can do with a [ListView](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/leanft/en/14.50-14.53/JS_SDKReference/Content/JavaScriptSDKReference/StdWin.ListView.html)